# Quality over SERPs (Search Engine Result Pages)

Tags: websites

I'm an experienced content writer and I write Search Engine friendly content writing. I am sorry to say that most of the people browsing internet consider top 10 results as the best results but then actually it's not.

The result you see there are Search Engine Optimized content and at times, got nothing to do with the quality of content (in terms of grammar, syntax and the like).

My question is simple:

> At times, I need to compromise the sentence structure as to include keywords/phrase. How do I tackle this issue?

Comment: SE optimization is overrated. It gives better ranks on the short run, but lower longterm. Many popular sites (facebook) have no SE optimization to speak of. They are popular because they provide the experience many users seek. If you have quality content, people will use your site. It will get popular by word of mouth. If you don't have the content that users find attractive, they won't use your sites no matter how high you are in search results. They will open your site once, close it, and never return. And they won't link to it. What you want is happy customers that tell all their friends.

Comment: I agree with @what, and in any case, changes to Google's algorithm mean that your site is more likely to hit the top of a search if your content is rich and meaningful, you have high quality sites link to you, and you incite interactivity through comments. I believe that Google  favour fresh content over static pages and mainly look for keywords in your H tags. From what I've read Google actually discount content that is needlessly keyword heavy.

Comment: This is also an issue in preparing resumes.  It might help clarify your question if you gave a concrete (not necessarily real) example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't.

If you can't incorporate the keyword smoothly, that keyword is irrelevant to the site, and you're doing both the site and the Internet as a whole a disservice. You will gather more visits - and more negative attention as soon as visitors detect they were deceived. Legitimate business lose customers that way - the very reasonable train of thought is "if they cheat at SEO, how sure am I they won't cheat at the cash register, or at warranty service?" - in essence, wrong keywords mark a site as dodgy.

Write actual, real, meaningful content. Not empty marketing blurbs but valid, helpful, professional articles.

I'm no SEO expert, but I maintain one site in a rather competitive area. I suggested the owner to write a series of advices to customers, short articles blog-like, detailing advanced techniques, common errors, proper maintenance, misconceptions, "industry horror stories", and so on. The language he uses is his own - not a smooth marketing slimeball, but an honest craftman, master of the trade, who is not afraid to call things their real names, or snark at idiocy of people who e.g. find a way to silence operation of a naturally noisy mechanism, completely compromising its purpose (and endangering their own lives) in the process.
That is incorporated in the page right next to a clear price list, testimonials of high-profile customers, contact and all the traditional elements of such a page.

The articles not only show in-depth knowledge of the author, they are quoted and linked on multiple fora on that subject. Result? Google's #1 on search for [main keyword][location], above competitors who pay SEO firms for increasing positioning of their domains. Sometimes he falls to #3 or so - but that's always temporary. SEO tricks don't beat actual content.

Comment: Addition: If you search for a certain keyword with Google, and you look at the results, you will notice that Google gives you results with **synonyms**, too. So obviously it is not necessary to incorporate *specific* keywords on a webpage to rank high for a certain keyword.